# If calling PQfinish, is there any benefit of calling PQcancel?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

If calling [PQFinish](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.2.11.9.1.2), which "closes the connection to the server", is there any benefit to calling [PQCancel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-cancel.html#id-1.7.3.14.3.1.3.1.2) beforehand?

i.e. if the connection is closed, would the PostgreSQL server cancel any in-progress queries on this connection, just as it would with PQCancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given this a test with just a `SELECT pg_sleep(120)` query. Even after PQFinish is called, connecting in via psql and running

```sql
SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc
```

still showed the query to be running.

So I think there is a benefit of running `PQCancel` - it would increase the chance of queries being cancelled and reducing resource use on the server.